# Who is the hobo in "The Polar Express"?

Tags: character-identification, polar-express

In *The Polar Express* (2004), we see this hobo:

[image: The Hobo]

He claims to be the 'King of the North Pole', but I'm not entirely sure.

**Who or what is he?**  I'm looking for an out-of-universe explanation regarding who or what this character is.

Comment: Is this question not a better fit for the movies and TV stack exchange site?

Comment: @JackGraveney I would consider this movie to fall under the category of fantasy therefore it's good for this site

Comment: Obviously we needed to hear Tom Hanks do yet another weird voice.

Comment: There's a wealth of info here. In short, the character is alternately the ghost of xmas past, a literal ghost (of someone who was riding the express before it was polar) and the holy ghost. http://polarexpress.wikia.com/wiki/Hobo

Comment: Related: [Character “Hobo” and his saying in the film The Polar Express?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63070/49)

Comment: OK, then, so not a nod to the Bogart-esque hobo character in "8 Ball Bunny"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few theories, probably all of them true.

### The Hobo is a literal ghost

In the DVD extras, there's an additional song which features a backstory about the "king of the train" being killed in a tunnel and haunting the train

### The Hobo is the "Ghost of Xmas Past"

There are more Dickens references in this film than you can shake a stick at. With the young boy representing the disbelieving Scrooge, the 'Three Ghosts' become the Hobo (Past) the Conductor (Present) and Santa (Future). Note the Ebeneezer Scrooge cameo about halfway through the film.

[image]

### Religious overtones

There's a fair argument to be made that the Hobo represents the 'Holy Ghost' of the classic Christian trinity with Santa as 'the Father" and the Conductor as the 'the Son'.

Comment: Oh, I need Tom Hanks to have represented all parts of the holy trinity and also Santa Clause in a single movie...

Comment: @GGMG - I think it's pretty reasonable to assume that Tom Hanks has developed a messiah complex given how often people say how "nice he is" on the internet